# Windows 10 asks for device PIN even though it doesn't exist

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I'm having trouble connecting my Bluetooth keyboard to my Computer.

 When I try to connect my keyboard Win10 tells me to enter the pin even though my keyboard doesn't have it.

 I tried using different combinations like 1234, 0000, restarting my pc and restarting the keyboard.

Laptop Brand: Acer 
Model: Aspire 5 
Bluetooth: Yes

See here:[image: Image attachment]

Thank You!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the necessary information to answer your question

Comment: It would help to tell us the brand and product type of the keyboard in question, and I also wonder if you looked in the manual? If there is indeed a pin required, the manual will tell you what the pin is or mention other install methods such as using a dongle that comes with the device, etc...

Comment: Ok. My Laptop brand is Acer, the model is Aspire 5 and sure enough, I have looked in the manual and there was nothing mentioning the device PIN

Comment: The keyboard documentation should list the BT connection PIN.

Comment: Let me check again :)

Comment: No, I have checked everything. Nothing was in there

Comment: What brand and model is the keyboard?

Comment: TECH-COM Model SSD-BKB-1100
Maybe there's a way to clear BT cache in Win10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

Step 1. Windows Key + R

Step 2. Enter `Devicepairingwizard`

Step 3. Select the device and connect with a passcode.

Hope this helped someone.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the solution!

I thought I'd offer a bit more details.

I ran the command mentioned, which brings up old Windows Control Panel-style wizard. At first, Windows couldn't find the keyboard. Then I ran it again, this time I quickly also used the "Add Bluetooth Device" function in modern UI. Now, the CP-style wizard found it. I clicked on it to add it. It asked for a password and mentioned something about possibly having to type in using the BT keyboard. I typed in a code 12345678 (this code didn't work before when entered in the same prompt showed in original post) using a connected USB keyboard and subsequently also typed the same code using the Bluetooth keyboard and hit Enter on the BT keyboard. Windows then started finishing installation process for the BT keyboard. Thank God it worked.

Sorry I couldn't offer screenshots. All the best.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1197143)